# Subprojects not seeing Ant variables set in NetBeans build.xml file

Tags: netbeans, ant

I have several different NetBeans projects linked together. I have a `MainProject` which links in `SubProject` as a compile-time library.

I am trying to modify the Ant `build.xml` script for `MainProject` to set a new Ant Variable. I can correctly set and see this variable in `MainProject` but the Ant `build.xml` script for `SubProject` does not see this variable.

My `build.xml` script in `MainProject`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MainProject" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project MainProject.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>

    <target name="-pre-init">
        <echo>MainProject Pre Init</echo>
        <echo>${ant.version}</echo>
        <property name="test.test.test" value="isset" />
        <echo>test.test.test=${test.test.test}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

My `build.xml` script in `SubProject`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="SubProject" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project SubProject.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
    <target name="-pre-init">
        <echo>SubProject Pre Init</echo>
        <echo>test.test.test=${test.test.test}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

Now when I run `clean and build` on `MainProject` I get the following output:

```
ant -f C:\\sandbox\\MainProject -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
MainProject Pre Init
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.7 compiled on April 9 2016
test.test.test=isset
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\sandbox\MainProject\build\built-clean.properties
SubProject Pre Init
test.test.test=${test.test.test}
SubProject.init:
SubProject.deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\sandbox\MainProject\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\sandbox\SubProject\build
SubProject.clean:
Deleting directory C:\sandbox\MainProject\build
clean:
MainProject Pre Init
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.7 compiled on April 9 2016
test.test.test=isset
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\sandbox\MainProject\build
Updating property file: C:\sandbox\MainProject\build\built-jar.properties
SubProject Pre Init
test.test.test=${test.test.test}
SubProject.init:
SubProject.deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\sandbox\SubProject\build
Updating property file: C:\sandbox\MainProject\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\sandbox\SubProject\build\classes
Created dir: C:\sandbox\SubProject\build\empty
Created dir: C:\sandbox\SubProject\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 1 source file to C:\sandbox\SubProject\build\classes
SubProject.compile:
Created dir: C:\sandbox\SubProject\dist
Copying 1 file to C:\sandbox\SubProject\build
Nothing to copy.
Building jar: C:\sandbox\SubProject\dist\SubProject.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\sandbox\SubProject\dist\SubProject.jar"
SubProject.jar:
Created dir: C:\sandbox\MainProject\build\classes
Created dir: C:\sandbox\MainProject\build\empty
Created dir: C:\sandbox\MainProject\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 1 source file to C:\sandbox\MainProject\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: C:\sandbox\MainProject\dist
Copying 1 file to C:\sandbox\MainProject\build
Copy libraries to C:\sandbox\MainProject\dist\lib.
Building jar: C:\sandbox\MainProject\dist\MainProject.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\sandbox\MainProject\dist\MainProject.jar"
jar:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

How do I get `SubProject` to see the state of the `${test.test.test}` variable as it is set by `MainProject`?

Edit - I am using NetBeans autogenerated `ant` build scripts for my project. Netbeans creates a `build-impl.xml` and a `build.xml`. When you invoke an `ant` process, it calls targets in `build-impl.xml`. Then `build-impl.xml` will call my custom code in `build.xml`. For example, running a `clean and build` in the NetBeans IDE will call the appropriate targets in `build-impl.xml`, and `build-impl.xml` will in turn call my custom code in `build.xml`. I can post the `build-impl.xml` scripts but they are just the standard ones generated by the Netbeans IDE.

Comment: I see target `-pre-init` in Main and sub as well. Any reason?

Comment: How is subproject's target is called ? Can post a reproducible build script? Also check if you can use subant - https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html

Comment: Rao, thanks for the reply. To answer you questions, I am using the NetBeans IDE. NetBeans creates a `build-impl.xml` and a `build.xml`. I posted my `build.xml` with my additional code. I can post the `build-impl.xml` but they are autogenerated by the IDE. When you run a build, it calls the targets in `build-impl.xml` which will pull in your custom code in `build.xml`. The `-pre-init` target is provided by the `build-impl.xml` and it will run your custom code before it runs the `init` target in the `build-impl.xml`. I did not see subant in the `build-impl.xml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the answer after investigating the `.build-impl.xml` script.

I found that `.build-impl.xml` for `MainProject` calls the build for `SubProject` with the following ant code:

```
<antcall target="-maybe-call-dep">
    <param name="call.built.properties" value="${built-jar.properties}"/>
    <param location="${project.SubProject}" name="call.subproject"/>
    <param location="${project.SubProject}/build.xml" name="call.script"/>
    <param name="call.target" value="jar"/>
    <param name="transfer.built-jar.properties" value="${built-jar.properties}"/>
    <param name="transfer.not.archive.disabled" value="true"/>
</antcall>
```

Now with this knowledge, I could see that `SubProject` only had access to a limited set of fields from `MainProject`. One of those fields, `${built-jar.properties}` is a path to a ant properties file. I created a new properties file sitting alongside the location of the `${built-jar.properties}` file. In the new properties file, I put all the ant variables I wanted stored. Now, in `SubProject` I created a variable pointing to the new file. This involved using a `dirname` command on the `${built-jar.properties}` file to get the directory. Then I called a `loadproperties` ant command to read all my variables.

It was quite a long workaround, but I finally got everything as I wanted it.

If anyone in the future is interested in all the code, I would be happy to edit my answer and put it in here. I didn't want to go through the extra work of doing that when it seemed unlikely anyone would refer to this answer.